# How to set up Apache2 hidden service?

Tags: ubuntu

Could someone make a simple guide on making a hidden service for apache2?

I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed and I'm just running a boring site.
(Hosting malware, botnets, spying kits, rats, crypters, ransomware, etc's source code)

Nothing fancy, but I would like the most security I can get.
Running Ubuntu if that helps.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327804/how-to-create-a-darknet-tor-web-site-in-linux/327805

Answer (score 1):

Well, Quite Simple... If you do have one website - just set it up, check that it's working just by IP and **make sure** that your whole apache config has **only one** uncommented `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` directive. As it's done - all you need is to make two lines in your `torrc` config:

```
HiddenServiceDir /path/to/tor/hidden_service/directory/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Basically - that's it! But keep in mind, that clearnet and darknet sites are *both* **and** *equal* - a websites, they do need protection. The protection techniques are task-dependent, but they're **a must**!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en

Make sure you read carefully in order to follow the Linux part and not anything on Windows or osx.